# Make a div content (googlemap) fullscreen

Tags: javascript, google-maps

iam trying to make a button that will turn the googlemap div into fullscreen..
this is what i have untill now, but it is not working correctly ..
problem is:
the map will only half loaded 
the code is below, and a screenshot

how can i repair this? where is the problem?
thanks in advance

http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/9365/halfload.gif

```
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function initialize() { 
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644); 
    var myOptions = { 
      zoom: 8, 
      center: latlng, 
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    }; 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 
  } 

function fs() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
 elem.style.position="absolute";
 elem.style.width="100%";
 elem.style.height="100%";
 elem.style.top="0px";
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";

}

</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="initialize()"> 
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px; height:300px"></div> 
  <a href="#" onclick ="fs()">makefullscreen</a>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinitialize the map after it's been maximized... here's the code:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function initialize() { 
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644); 
    var myOptions = { 
      zoom: 8, 
      center: latlng, 
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    }; 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 
  } 

function fs() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
 elem.style.position="absolute";
 elem.style.width="100%";
 elem.style.height="100%";
 elem.style.top="0px";
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";

}

</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="initialize()"> 
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px; height:300px"></div> 
  <a href="#" onclick ="fs(); initialize();">makefullscreen</a>
</body> 
</html>
```

Hope this Helps,
Gale